# WebApi HttpPost body content null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, postman

In my WebApi I have a `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` method, the get method is working fine and the post method is called but the body content is always null, unless used in a `HttpRequestMessage`. I tried providing the body content in a string format(preferred datatype) aswell as in a model but neither one of those methods worked. I also tried switching the content type without success. Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or how I can easily get the variable data from the `HttpRequestMessage`, which in the example below is "test".

Method 1:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[Route("api/v1/AddItem")]      
public IHttpActionResult AddItem([FromBody]string filecontent, string companycode)
{
   MessageBox.Show(filecontent);

   Return Ok("");
}
```

Method 2 (with model):

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[Route("api/v1/AddItem")]      
public IHttpActionResult AddItem([FromBody]ItemXML filecontent, string companycode)
{
   MessageBox.Show(filecontent.XMLContent);

   Return Ok("");
}
```

Model:

```
public class ItemXML
{
  public ItemXML(string content)
  {
    XMLContent = content;
  }
  public string XMLContent { get; set; }      
}
```

Method 3:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[Route("api/v1/AddItem")]      
public IHttpActionResult AddItem(HttpRequestMessage filecontent, string companycode)
{
   var content = filecontent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;    
   MessageBox.Show(content);

   Return Ok("");
}
```

Method 3 content string ("test" is the provided value): "       content "------WebKitFormBoundarydu7BJizb50runvq0\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filecontent\"\r\n\r\n\"**test**\"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarydu7BJizb50runvq0--\r\n"    string"

Comment: show how the request is being made. are you posting JSON or form-data? assuming form because of the filecontent parameter name

Comment: I tried it both ways, without success however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model store data to be sent to server

```
public class Model {
    public string filecontent { get; set;}
    public string companycode { get; set;}
}
```

Update Action

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/v1/AddItem")]      
public IHttpActionResult AddItem([FromBody]Model model) {
    if(ModelStat.IsValid) {
        return Ok(model); //...just for testing
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

On the client make sure the request is being sent properly. In this case going to use JSON.

```
public client = new HttpClient();

var model = new {
    filecontent = "Hello World",
    companycode = "test"
};

var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);
```

If using another type of client ensure that the data being sent is formatted correctly for the Web API action to accept the request.

Reference [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: This did the trick, do you know by any chance why it didn't work before? is it because companycode wasn't included in the model?

Comment: @Alim I believe it was a combination of the controller not recognizing the request because of how the the action was defined and format of how the data was being sent.

Comment: @Alim I included a reference link on how to use `[FromBody]`

Comment: You don't have to use [FromBody] with a object. It gets the information from the body by default since it is not a "simple" type as defined in your link